# Ruby on rails .erb file

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

My `.erb` file does not execute the code inside `<%= %>` as ruby code. For example:: 
`<%= puts "almost"%>`, when rendered is just `<%= puts "almost"%>`. The erb engine does not even process anything. This means that NOTHING inside <%= %> is being processed .Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try `<%= "almost" %>` if you want `almost` as the output

Comment: Do you mean your rendered HTML will literally contain `<%= puts "almost" %>` as though the erb engine did nothing?

Comment: You will need to provide more information; if it's rendering precisely `<%= puts "almost" %>` then something has gone very wrong. Note that writing to `stdout`, while certainly a valid thing to do, is almost never what you want in a view template.

Comment: Add your exact code to your question.

Comment: Yes, my HTML is literally outputting <%= puts "almost" %> as though the erb engine did not do anything

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information for anyone to help you. It looks like your web server is just serving your files as static content. What server are you using? How is it configured? What web framework?

Comment: @Terminator101 Accepting an answer that doesn't address the question seems dysfunctional. The answer you've accepted is 1) incorrect, and 2) not related to your problem as you've described it.

Comment: It worked for me though. There is no t a problem with the server or anything since everything else works just fine

Comment: If the issue was that it wasn't evaluating the code at all, and rendering what was contained in the erb fine verbatim without executing, then the answer isn't correct, for the reason I stated in the comment. The code inside the erb escape is executed regardless of the equals sign-all the equals sign does is signify that the result of the evaluation should be rendered during the template processing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Anything inside <% %> will be evaluated as ruby code, and anything inside <%= %> will be outputed as html. So when you do <%= puts "almost" %> it is outputded directly as HTML. You can solve this using

```
<% puts "almost" %>
```

or

```
<%= "almost" %>.
```

Comment: No; `<%= puts "almost" %>` will render the return value of `puts`. All `<%= %>` does it output the results of evaluating the Ruby code inside it. In your example, `"almost"` is a string, so that's what's rendered to the client. The contents are evaluated: that's how come you can use it to render the output of a variable, a helper method, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing erb expressions with Ruby code. Use `<% %>` to have arbitrary Ruby code executed.

```
<% puts "almost" %>
```

Comment: The code in `<%= %>` will still be evaluated; the issue here is either (a) it's not being processed by ERb at *all*, or (b) they wanted to have `almost` rendered on the *client*, or something else. It's tough to say given the presentation.